# Are there knots that can be distinguished between by the Jones polynomial that the HOMFLY polynomial cannot distiguish?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Obviously the HOMFLY polynomial is a more superior invariant than the Jones polynomial since it is a geralisation of the Jones. 
However, are there knots that can be distinguished between by the Jones polynomial that the HOMFLY polynomial cannot distiguish?

Answer (score 4):

No: as you mention, the HOMFLY polynomial specializes to the Jones polynomial, so if the HOMFLY polynomials of two knots are equal then their Jones polynomials must also be equal.